# how to ansible role1 ouput + role2 output = print result

Tags: math, ansible

hi can some one please help me here i have r1.yml ouput registered files count from /etc/   and r2.yml also registred files count how can i combine both and show in testplaybook.yml below ?

how can i show both files total in below testplaybook.yml?

```
# testplaybook.yml
---
- hosts: webservers
 - include_tasks: r1.yml
 - include_tasks: r2.yml

# r1.yml  ouput etc count is= 100 
#r2.yml.   output etc count is =100
#total wan to show from r1.yml +. r2.yml =200

---------------------------
r1.yml

-name: get files count on host1 /etc/
 shell: ls /etc | wc -l
 register: ouput1



r2.yml

-name: get files count on host2 /etc/
 shell: ls /etc | wc -l
 register: ouput2
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a playbook by each host You can try as below

r1.yml

```
- name: get files count on /etc/
  shell: ls /etc | wc -l
  register: __number_of_files

- name: Set count of number of number of files
  set_fact:
    count: "{{ __number_of_files.stdout_lines.0 }}"
```

and testplaybook.yml

```
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
  - include_tasks: r1.yml

  - name: Print number of files on servers
    debug:
      msg: Number of files on servers are {{ groups['webservers'] | map('extract',hostvars,'count') | map('int') | list | sum}}
    run_once: yes
    connection: local
```

With this doesn't matter how many hosts you have on webservers group.

Comment: thanks much helpful.   can I do same for webserver output + dbserver output  ?  and total sum both ?

Comment: Modify `hosts: webservers,database` and

    `msg: Number of files on servers are {{ groups['webservers'] | map('extract',hostvars,'count') | map('int') | list | sum + groups['database'] | map('extract',hostvars,'count') | map('int') | list | sum}}`